# Continued while loop ignoring if statements

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

So I have a rock paper scissors game. Upon the user completing their designated # of rounds, they are prompted whether or not they want to continue, and how many rounds they want to play this time. However, no matter what # I choose, the loop goes on forever. ignoring the if statements to end the loop. 
Heres the while loop portion of my code:

```
while again == True:

    print("It is ",name,"'s", " turn. What do you pick (R)ock, (P)aper, or (S)cissors?: ", sep = '',end = "")
    print()
    print()
    user = str.lower(input())
    print()

    if user != "s" and user != "r" and user != "p":
        print("Invalid input. Try again.")
        print()
        continue
    else:

        if user == "r":
            userchoice = "rock"

            rock()
            print()

            print(name,"picks Rock!")
        if user == "p":
           userchoice = "paper"

           paper()
           print()
           print(name,"picks Paper!")


        elif user == "s":
            userchoice = "scissors"

            X()
            print()
            print(name,"picks Scissors!")


        print("Now it's computers turn....")
        print('.')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('.')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('.')
        print()

        cpu = random.randint(1,3)
        if cpu == 1:
            cpuchoice = "rock"
            rock()
            print()
            print(" Computer picks rock!")

        if cpu == 2:
            cpuchoice = "paper"
            paper()
            print()
            print("Computer picks paper!")

        elif cpu ==3:
            cpuchoice = "scissors"
            X()
            print()
            print("Computer picks scissors!")


        if cpuchoice == "rock" and userchoice == "scissors" or (cpuchoice == "paper" and userchoice == "rock") or cpuchoice == "scissors" and userchoice == "paper":
            print("Computer wins this round!")
            cscore += 1
        elif cpuchoice == userchoice:
            print("Draw!")
        else:
            print(name,"Wins this round!")
            uscore +=1

        print()
        itt += 1
        print(itt)
        print(rounds)
        print(again)
        print(uscore)
        print(cscore)
        if itt == rounds and uscore == cscore:
            print("It's still a tie! Let's go one more round")
            print()
            itt -= 1
        elif cscore + uscore == rounds:




            if uscore > cscore:
                print(name,"wins!")
            else:
                print("Computer wins!")
            again = input("Play again? Enter 0 to quit.Anything else to continue")
            if again != "0":
                  rounds = input("How many rounds this time?")
                  itt = 0
                  uscore = 0
                  cscore = 0
                  again = True

            else:
                again = False
```

Comment: You have a few nested ifs.  I would work with a reduced piece of code that just contains the loop and if statements that aren't working.  Debug that code until its working then add all the rest back in.

Comment: The program works for me. Pressing 0 quits it.

Comment: `while again == True:` is an anti-pattern. Just use `while True:`, and when the user says they want to stop use `break` to end the loop immediately.

Comment: And if you really want to use a variable, just write `while again:`.

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation for the 'again != 0' block is off, I don't know the exact rules Python uses when parsing whitespace but it might be the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your issue has to do with the check `elif cscore + uscore == rounds:`. If you had a tie and ran an extra round, your two scores won't add up correctly afterwards. Since you're checking for exact equality, the last part of the code won't ever run and the game will not end.

While you could fix that pretty simply by using `>=` instead of `==`, I think that checking `itt` (which should get a better name, like `round_counter`) directly might make more sense than adding the scores together. Or heck, you could restructure the whole thing like this:

```
if itt >= rounds:
    if uscore == cscore:
        # tied, play another round

    else:
        # game over, say who won, ask about playing again
```